# how to move from one actvitiy to anther in android?

Tags: android

I have written the code but this code is not working to move from one activity to another can anybody help me out how to fix the error?
When I am installing the app on device it is saying unfortunately app stopped working.
Here is the code. This is MainActivity file

```
package com.example.lalit.activvity2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is SecondActivity code

```
package com.example.lalit.activvity2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please can anybody help me out how should i fix the error?

Comment: Post your error log

Comment: Have you include both class in Android manifest file ?

Comment: use this
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

add your class name in manifest file like this :

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your class in manifest file

`<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>`

and if again it will throw an error then post your log error msg in the comment